# PHP errors when trying to apply geo location

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to do some geolocating to display certain phone numbers in the header of my WordPress website. Unfortunately when I apply the code below i get the following PHP error:

> [17-Sep-2014 19:48:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty needle in /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada/framework/headers/header-v4.php on line 87
>
> [17-Sep-2014 19:48:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty needle in /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/themes/Avada/framework/headers/header-v4.php on line 90

```
<?php
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $url = "http://freegeoip.net/json/" . $ip;
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    $city = print_r($data['city'], true);
    $state = print_r($data['region_code'], true);
    $kings_orlando = "Altamonte Springs Apopka Casselberry College Park Heathrow Lake Mary Longwood Maitland Orlando Oviedo Windermere Winter Park Winter Springs";
     
    if ((strpos($kings_orlando,$city) !== false) AND ($state == "FL")) {
        echo '<a href="tel:1-407-270-2112">1-407-270-2112</a>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<a href="tel:1-954-753-9436">1-954-753-9436</a>';
    }
?>
```

Not only do I get the error but my footer disappears as well. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the `header-v4.php` file, lines 85 to 92.

Comment: What's the value of `$city` right before the if statement? Are you verifying that _freegeoip.net_ is passing back legitimate data? A lot of times if those services aren't able to locate certain information, it'll return an empty string as a placeholder thus resulting in the above error message without the proper checks. Try `echo $city;` or `print_r($data);` to see an overview of what data is returned. `$city` is probably an empty string...

Comment: You have an empty needle, fix it. What else is there to say beyond what's in the error message?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, lines 85 - 92 are already in the code provided. It is if statement all the way to end of the code provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking a guess here: You're trying this locally. Hence, your IP address is `127.0.0.1`.

For this IP freegeoip.net – obviously – doesn't know a city. You can see this by just looking at the output: https://freegeoip.net/json/127.0.0.1

So you have to expect that `$city` is simply empty. Catch this problem by doing this:

```
if (!empty($city) AND (strpos($kings_orlando,$city) !== false) AND ($state == "FL")) {
```

(Of course, this can also happen with "real" IP addresses – the GeoLite database that freegeoip.net is using is far from complete, especially on a city level.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, using this freegeoip.net service is wrong :) (as long as you need it for more than just a country). It's highly inaccurate and often unavailable, but maybe it's just me who had a lot of problems with it even in a small startup-website.
2. Secondly - using `$city = print_r($data['city'], true);` is wrong.

   You should only do `$city = $data['city'];` if even that.

Those warnings you get mean that `$city` variable is empty, which is very possible (see: point 1. of my answer ;). Try other geolocating services or make sure you handle situations, where city is not provided in  returned JSON.

Comment: Thanks for that Kleskowy. Do you recommend other geolocating services?

Comment: [MaxMind's solution](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/) looks quite promising, but I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: Those two lines do the same thing.. there's no problem there http://codepad.org/9p21dQ9m. He simply needs to error-check his inputs like the error says. By step: 1) Confirm the error, examine the variable that the error suggests is empty or of the wrong type. 2) Investigate why it's empty and fix that case or account for the condition before trying to use it.